# Custom business service in data validation manager

Tags: siebel

I have DVM fired from task flow. There is a set of certain rules, and one of them looks like this:

`InvokeServiceMethod("StringUtilsBS","matchRegExp","source=eval([Client Last Name]),pattern='" + [&Mask]'","result") <> "INVALID"`

The business service itself works correctly in the BS simulator: I can see valid results and logs (tracing is enabled). But when DVM is invoking this rule, there is no trace log, it looks like the service is not launching at all.

BS was compiled into all possible locales. In client's cfg I've added `Business Service Query Access List=StringUtilsBS`, same thing is done in "Administration: Server Configuration: Enterprise: Parameters" for a thin client.

No luck so far. Tested in high interactivity and open UI for either thin or thick clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used the data validation manager... However, I would start by checking that your rule expression is ok, because InvokeServiceMethod syntax is quite ugly and there is a chance that you have a typo somewhere in it. In fact, I think there is one:

```
pattern='" + [&Mask]'",        <-- this is what you have
pattern='" + [&Mask] + "'",    <-- but shouldn't it be like this?
```

If that doesn't fix it, I would create a calculated field in the same BC where `[Client Last Name]` is, with the same expression. You'd have to replace `[&Mask]` with something else, of course, but it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: yep, exactly. the correct syntax was

`<..>pattern=" + [&Zip_Mask],<..>`

thanks.